# How to move a file in the jenkins workspace?

Tags: shell, file, jenkins, move, workspace

Suppose in the jenkins workspace is a folder named "files", inside the folder is a file named test.xlsx. While building a job i want to move the content of test.xlsx into another file.

i tried:

```
mv test.xlsx test2.xlsx
```

but i didnt know where to put this command. Also not sure about the command/path

```
mv files/test.xlsx files/test.xlsx
```

Comment: Are you using the pipeline model?

Comment: no the job is not using a pipeline model

Comment: Are you getting any error?